# Unable to login if network cable is attached

Tags: networking, 18.04

Running Ubuntu 18.04 and am currently unable to login if my network cable is attached. If I unplug it I can sign in fine and then plug it back in (after login has completed) and all networking appears fully functional.

Any thoughts on how to fix it so I can go back to signing into my machine without having to unplug the network cable each time?

`sudo lshw -C network` output:

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 78
       serial: 14:4f:8a:2c:67:0d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-21-generic firmware=36.9f0a2d68.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 memory:edc00000-edc01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx106530ba9618
       serial: 10:65:30:ba:96:18
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=full ip=10.118.144.46 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Just found out a coworker is also running into the same issue (also solved by logging in with the network cable unattached) so perhaps caused by a recent bad update?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Describe your network cabling from the computer to the hub/switch/router. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables?

Comment: Edited question to include `lshw` output. Cable is cat 6. Unable to describe cabling to hub/switch/router since I have no idea (or access) once it goes into the wall-jack by my desk.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Desktop or server installation? Now lets look at `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Edited question with additional output as requested.

Comment: So far everything looks normal. Desktop installation, yes? Does the computer have a SSD? Try this... reboot the computer... at the login screen, BEFORE you type anything, look in the upper-right corner of the screen... can you need the network icon... and does it look "normal", or show disconnected? With the cable connected, exactly what happens when you try to login and it fails?

Comment: This is a laptop. Dell Precision and occurs both with or without the docking station. If I reboot and look at the icon before signing in with the cable attached it briefly shows a question mark before turning into the normal three box icon. If I attempt to login with the cable attached a spinner just spins endlessly to the left of the signin box (I've given it up to several minutes it never completes the signin). If I reboot with the cable unattached I can sign in fine and plug the cable in and have networking (after restarting the network-manager service).

Comment: Interesting. Reboot with cable disconnected. Sign in. Connect the cable. BEFORE restarting network-manager, show me `sudo lshw -C network` again. Describe the network icon now... is it a question mark, or the 3-box icon, or something else? Now you can restart NM.

Comment: Apparently restarting network-manager wasn't actually necessary in my workaround. Logging in with the cable unattached and then attaching it and running `lshw` shows the exact same output even without restarting network-manager (and the icon is the three boxes and networking works OK etc). Given this also impacted a coworker on Ubuntu and there was a kernel update yesterday morning I think I'll just try to rollback to the previous kernel and hope that helps, if not guess I'll need to do a reinstall. Thanks for all your help @heynnema

Comment: Turns out I didn't need to resort to a nuclear option. Did an apt update and upgrade (had tried this yesterday but no packages were upgradeable at the time) and everything appears to be functioning normally as it was prior to yesterday's update, so whatever wonky package was upgraded yesterday must have had a fix rolled out thankfully.

Comment: Look in `/var/log/dpkg.log` or `/var/log/dpkg.log.1` to see what things were updated in the last day or so. Report back.

Comment: Posted everything updated yesterday and today at https://pastebin.com/uEqsCBn1 there are several hundred entries, trying to take a quick glance nothing stuck out as getting updated both yesterday and today so doesn't look like it was a particular package that was broke and fixed, I'm guessing something broke due to the kernel update (thus it would only appear once, in today's). But the update also solved the problem for my coworker so certainly not an anomaly (we both have the exact same model laptop so perhaps something that only effected certain network cards or similar).

Comment: The logs were TL;DR. But, I'm glad it's working for both of you now :-)